# Spring AMQP in RPC mode with disconnected client

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am using a Spring AMQP in RPC mode.
I have the following case :

- the client send a message
- the consumer do not reply in time
- the client is stopped, so can not receive the response

Is it possible to detect that the client is no more there so the consumer can make treatment with the response message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; producers and consumers are completely isolated and independent; you need some other mechanism to communicate this state.

Comment: Thank you for this rapid answer.